# borg retention --keep-hourly not clear

Tags: backup

I have the retention policy set to -H 12  -d 7 -w 4 -m 6 -y 1
I guess meaning keep 2 backups on current day, 7 archives of last day, 1 per week during 4 week ...

I found strange that all my daily archives up to one month old are kept

```
[root@host id]# borg prune --list -n -vvvvv -H 12  -d 7 -w 4 -m 6 -y 1 $REPOSITORY                    
Keeping archive: 20230914-0002                        Thu, 2023-09-14 00:02:35 [530d5441090e5a1d12e995f6ea7615dd
Keeping archive: 20230913-0002                        Wed, 2023-09-13 00:02:06 [61d40e62b91757118e42dfd683f833ae
Keeping archive: 20230912-0002                        Tue, 2023-09-12 00:02:32 [8e0fa07ca34b64ea56ec71c6274e5061
Keeping archive: 20230911-0002                        Mon, 2023-09-11 00:02:33 [8f1eb604450950324f75b873ce6d82ee
Keeping archive: 20230910-0002                        Sun, 2023-09-10 00:02:06 [bf68e79c31eb4ba0ace5386b2d58e4f0
Keeping archive: 20230909-0002                        Sat, 2023-09-09 00:02:32 [15ecf7ce9ddbf2fc97e92b4997ec4a0a
Keeping archive: 20230908-0002                        Fri, 2023-09-08 00:02:14 [d15bbda950c34d7a880faee52c17e7a5
Keeping archive: 20230907-0002                        Thu, 2023-09-07 00:02:14 [87132d0e5eb71e8d4d355a7e30d7cdd4
Keeping archive: 20230906-0002                        Wed, 2023-09-06 00:02:14 [dab1ba672eb0cc7b8a9f42c71e0ebee7
Keeping archive: 20230905-0002                        Tue, 2023-09-05 00:02:14 [6d0cad2140d88cebcfe79b011e264fc8
Keeping archive: 20230904-0002                        Mon, 2023-09-04 00:02:13 [c37dbc37fa9f30e96c7442d50562d50a
Keeping archive: 20230903-0002                        Sun, 2023-09-03 00:02:13 [7fa6b03aa89255acf8e4f28b8460cd02
Keeping archive: 20230902-0002                        Sat, 2023-09-02 00:02:13 [342c5c7c5e9b01c67e6b27ad00891584
Keeping archive: 20230901-0002                        Fri, 2023-09-01 00:02:13 [54b0e5a167267f98726b5236bb1ce88e
Keeping archive: 20230831-0002                        Thu, 2023-08-31 00:02:13 [0294f4fae56356a8e4c2ebb895794249
Keeping archive: 20230830-0002                        Wed, 2023-08-30 00:02:13 [cd47c318cd231b265fe618228dbe7c49
Keeping archive: 20230829-0002                        Tue, 2023-08-29 00:02:14 [092b95a41ad25851692f8510d45b7912
Keeping archive: 20230828-1833                        Mon, 2023-08-28 18:33:29 [c8c856329e13988b398c0673298109df
Keeping archive: 20230827-0002                        Sun, 2023-08-27 00:02:03 [83b54bd4f767055d0c35804b033184fb
Keeping archive: 20230820-0002                        Sun, 2023-08-20 00:02:03 [28b15db46aae27629ac963ce3a0cd172
Keeping archive: 20230813-0002                        Sun, 2023-08-13 00:02:03 [9b1101ccdeb285369b6a08a63af104f3
Keeping archive: 20230806-0002                        Sun, 2023-08-06 00:02:03 [342284234f5c43051f2f89c900f28507
Keeping archive: 20230731-0002                        Mon, 2023-07-31 00:02:03 [40ea88413090df20e75f1b72809fbae4
Keeping archive: 20230730-0002                        Sun, 2023-07-30 00:02:02 [1edea8fa380fe8592bb3619ffef35038
Keeping archive: 20230630-0002                        Fri, 2023-06-30 00:02:02 [cfed932651291ed797401ff35956c3c1
Keeping archive: 20230531-0002                        Wed, 2023-05-31 00:02:01 [649a19bee90249c3bade24c89de3c611
Keeping archive: 20230430-0002                        Sun, 2023-04-30 00:02:04 [ec986349f9e62bf657add5fa4ba430b2
```

I don't understand why for example, "Would prune:     20230907-0002" is not purged.

This seems due to the `--keep-hourly` option, if I remove the `--keep-hourly`, a lot of archive are pruned

```
[root@host id]# borg prune --list -n -vvvvv  -d 7 -w 4 -m 6 -y 1 $REPOSITORY            
Keeping archive: 20230914-0002                        Thu, 2023-09-14 00:02:35 [530d5441090e5a1d12
Keeping archive: 20230913-0002                        Wed, 2023-09-13 00:02:06 [61d40e62b91757118e
Keeping archive: 20230912-0002                        Tue, 2023-09-12 00:02:32 [8e0fa07ca34b64ea56
Keeping archive: 20230911-0002                        Mon, 2023-09-11 00:02:33 [8f1eb604450950324f
Keeping archive: 20230910-0002                        Sun, 2023-09-10 00:02:06 [bf68e79c31eb4ba0ac
Keeping archive: 20230909-0002                        Sat, 2023-09-09 00:02:32 [15ecf7ce9ddbf2fc97
Keeping archive: 20230908-0002                        Fri, 2023-09-08 00:02:14 [d15bbda950c34d7a88
Would prune:     20230907-0002                        Thu, 2023-09-07 00:02:14 [87132d0e5eb71e8d4d
Would prune:     20230906-0002                        Wed, 2023-09-06 00:02:14 [dab1ba672eb0cc7b8a
Would prune:     20230905-0002                        Tue, 2023-09-05 00:02:14 [6d0cad2140d88cebcf
Would prune:     20230904-0002                        Mon, 2023-09-04 00:02:13 [c37dbc37fa9f30e96c
Keeping archive: 20230903-0002                        Sun, 2023-09-03 00:02:13 [7fa6b03aa89255acf8
Would prune:     20230902-0002                        Sat, 2023-09-02 00:02:13 [342c5c7c5e9b01c67e
Would prune:     20230901-0002                        Fri, 2023-09-01 00:02:13 [54b0e5a167267f9872
Keeping archive: 20230831-0002                        Thu, 2023-08-31 00:02:13 [0294f4fae56356a8e4
Would prune:     20230830-0002                        Wed, 2023-08-30 00:02:13 [cd47c318cd231b265f
Would prune:     20230829-0002                        Tue, 2023-08-29 00:02:14 [092b95a41ad2585169
Would prune:     20230828-1833                        Mon, 2023-08-28 18:33:29 [c8c856329e13988b39
Keeping archive: 20230827-0002                        Sun, 2023-08-27 00:02:03 [83b54bd4f767055d0c
Keeping archive: 20230820-0002                        Sun, 2023-08-20 00:02:03 [28b15db46aae27629a
Keeping archive: 20230813-0002                        Sun, 2023-08-13 00:02:03 [9b1101ccdeb285369b
Would prune:     20230806-0002                        Sun, 2023-08-06 00:02:03 [342284234f5c43051f
Keeping archive: 20230731-0002                        Mon, 2023-07-31 00:02:03 [40ea88413090df20e7
Would prune:     20230730-0002                        Sun, 2023-07-30 00:02:02 [1edea8fa380fe8592b
Keeping archive: 20230630-0002                        Fri, 2023-06-30 00:02:02 [cfed932651291ed797
Keeping archive: 20230531-0002                        Wed, 2023-05-31 00:02:01 [649a19bee90249c3ba
Keeping archive: 20230430-0002                        Sun, 2023-04-30 00:02:04 [ec986349f9e62bf657
```

The borg version used

```
[root@uaeqmm11 cdelarue]# borg --version
borg 1.1.18
```

I tried also the keep-within 2d, it generates a Keeping archive that at 8 days old :( ...

> As an example, --keep-daily 7 means to keep the latest backup on each day, up to 7 most recent days with backups (**days without backups do not count**).

Does this mean that it for example there is no backup on weekend, it could be up to 9 days that archive are kept ?

Comment: I guess I can auto answer.  When I use keep-hourly 12, it means keep all 12 last archives, remove others. If 12 items can be found within the day, ok keep them even if old.
And once elected by the hourly, the keep daily only consider the next one. I should reduce my keep-hourly parameter.